# How to create a mock session for session of AngularJs with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, automated-tests

In AngularJs I have to test a filter using jasmine. I have set studentNameFormat in session in a controller. I have a filter like this:

```
angular.module('course.filters').filter('studentName',['Session',
    function (Session) {
    return function (student) {
        var format = Session.getState().studentNameFormat;

        if(format == '0') {
            return   student.firstName + " " + student.lastName;
        }
       else{
            return student.lastName + student.firstName;
        }
    };
}]);
```

In order to test a method in Jasmine I need to pass the a Session object to that method. How can a create a mock session variable?

```
I have test filter like:

describe('studentName', function () {

    'use strict';

        var $filter;
        var student;
        var session;
        beforeEach(function () {
            module('course.filters');

            inject(function (_$filter_, _Session_) {

                $filter = _$filter_;
                session = _Session_;

            });
            patient = {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }

            session.setState({
               studentNameFormat: 1
            });

        });

        it('return full lastName full FirstName if given 1', function () {
            console.log(patient);
            var studentFilter = $filter('studentName');

            expect(studentFilter (student)).toEqual("Doe John");

        });
```

And it gives me error sessionProvider not defined.
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SessionProvider <- Session <- studentFilter

Comment: Is Session a service you inject into your Angular components?

Comment: It will actually help if you could include some of your testing code or upload it into a JS Fiddle/Plnkr.